# TargetFrameworkVersion problem of Xamarin.Form.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a beginner at Xamarin.Forms.

My project has to support Android 6 and I create a brand new project with Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1451, and then set the Compile using Android version to Android 6.

Now visual Studio reports this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Sample.Android (v6.0) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (9.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Sample.Android. Sample.Android
```

It seems the current version Xamarin.Forms does not support Android 6, right?

How can I solve this? Whether I can only use a lower version Xamarin.Forms?

Thank you.

Comment: Downgrade your Xamarin.Forms Nuget package [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell). Or edit your csproj file for a specific version number

Comment: @Shaw However, how can I get to know which version Xamarin.Forms can support Android 6?

Comment: I assume you have to check that manually from the dependency as the answer below (select big version number first to get close, and check minor versions afterwards).

Comment: Is it helpful for you?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Yes, I forgot to mark the answer. I am sorry about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the [Target Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=macos#target-framework) (also known as `compileSdkVersion`) is the specific Android framework version (API level) that your app is compiled for at build time. This setting specifies what APIs your app expects to use when it runs, but it has no effect on which APIs are actually available to your app when it is installed. As a result, changing the `Target Framework` setting does not change runtime behavior.

The `Target Framework` identifies which library versions your application is linked against – this setting determines which APIs you can use in your app. For example, if you want to use the some method that was introduced in `Android 6.0`, you must set the `Target Framework` to API Level `23` or later.

We recommend that you always compile with the latest available Target Framework version.

So you don't need to set the Compile using Android version to Android 6,if you want it support Android 6,you just need set the [Target Android Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=macos#target-android-version) or [Minimum Android Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=macos#minimum-android-version) to android 6.

And you could see the Android version(`MonoAndroid Version`) that `Xamarin.Forms` depends on when you open the NugetPackage Manager.

[image]